Downgrade to 5.75 from 5.79 possible because of php 7.4 issues
i made an mistake on my Drupal 7 installation. For now I can't update to get it run with php 8.1. Therefore I got an php warning for the flexmailer in civicrm but I can't use php81 for now.
can I downgrade for so long as I get my Drupal 7 updated for php 8.x?

Can you leave CiviCRM at 5.79 and switch php to 7.4?

The only way to downgrade CiviCRM is if you have a backup of your CRM database from that version. If so, then you should restore the backup and replace the new CiviCRM code with the older code & clear caches. Then you will have successfully downgraded.
